# React Google Places Autocomplete React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-api

I am new to react and using apis, I have installed the tool using: npm install --save react-google-places-autocomplete, and have loaded the script for google maps api with the places library included, in the index.html file.

At this point I have added a simple GooglePlacesAutocomplete component. On the website, when I begin typing my hometown, mississauga, the loading sign quickly appears and disappears, and I get a console error:

"index.js:1 You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account  For more information on usage limits and the Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage"

even as I type just the first letter. However, when I type "los", I get the same error above for the first two letters, but I get location suggestions when I type the third. Why is this?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';
//Used to access google's location autocomplete api and its provided css

import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';
import 'react-google-places-autocomplete/dist/index.min.css';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       term:"",
       location:"",
       sortBy: "best_match"
     }
     this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this);
     this.handleLocationChange = this.handleLocationChange.bind(this);
     this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this);
     this.handleSearchByEnter = this.handleSearchByEnter.bind(this);

     //These are the options by which you can sort the returned Yelp object
       this.sortByOptions = {
       'Best Match': "best_match",
       'Highest Rated': "rating",
       'Most Reviewed': "review_count"
     }
   }

     //Gets the CSS class for the sorting option
     getSortByClass(sortByOption) {
       if(this.state.sortBy === sortByOption) {
         return 'active';
       } else {
         return '';
       }
     }
     //This function automatically rerenders the business list when a new sort by option is chosen to reflect it.
     handleSortByChange(sortByOption) {
       //Recall setState is asynchronous, so include a callback function called with updated sortByOption,
        this.setState({
          sortBy: sortByOption,
        }, ()=> {
          this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
        })
     }

     handleTermChange(event) {
       this.setState({
         term: event.target.value
       })
     }

     handleLocationChange(event) {
       this.setState({
         location: event.target.value
       })
     }

     handleSearch(event) {
       this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
       event.preventDefault();
     }

     handleSearchByEnter(event) {
       if(event.which === 13) {
         document.getElementById('submit').click();
       }
     }
   renderSortByOptions() {
    //Object.keys() returns array of property names
    //Array.map() takes that array and returns another array of list elements with a key of that particular sortByOption
    return Object.keys(this.sortByOptions).map(sortByOption=> {
      let sortByOptionValue = this.sortByOptions[sortByOption];
      //Keys are special react attributes that must be included when rendering list elements
      return <li key={sortByOptionValue} className={this.getSortByClass(sortByOptionValue)} onClick={this.handleSortByChange.bind(this, sortByOptionValue)}>{sortByOption}</li>
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar" onKeyPress={this.handleSearchByEnter}>
        <div className="SearchBar-sort-options">
          <ul>
            {this.renderSortByOptions()}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="SearchBar-fields">
          <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange={this.handleTermChange}/>
          <input id="location" placeholder="Where?" onChange={this.handleLocationChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete/>
        </div>

        <div className="SearchBar-submit">
          <a id="submit" onClick= {this.handleSearch}>Let's Go</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The error makes it sound like you haven't set-up your API key for the Google Places component. Did you create a key and set it up? (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key ). From the docs for the react-google-places-autocomplete package, it looks like *may* pass the key as an apiKey parameter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-places-autocomplete, but in the example you posted, it doesn't look like you're doing that.

Comment: Thank you for your greeting and help! I have since added the apiKey prop but now it just shows "Loading" without disappearing, no matter what I enter. Also, how did you glean this suggestion from the npm page? From what I understood, all I needed to do was load the script in the index.html file with the key parameter, which I did, and use the component without parameters as seen in the example. Thank you again for your help! @antun

Comment: The NPM page had this:
> if you pass down the apiKey prop to the component, you can skip loading the Google Maps JavaScript API, as the component will inject that script on the page.
That's why I said *may* in my comment, since it sounds like you can *either* pass the apiKey option *or* pass the apiKey in the script include.

Are there any console errors, or HTTP response errors now?

Comment: Ohh okay that makes sense. There is an error in index.js: "You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.". I tried fixing this by removing the script in the index.html file. But then got the error: "[react-google-places-autocomplete]: Google script not loaded".

Comment: I forgot to tag you @antun ^

Comment: The `[react-google-places-autocomplete]: Google script not loaded` error seems to be irrelevant, at least for me. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/Tintef/react-google-places-autocomplete/blob/master/src/GooglePlacesAutocomplete/index.js#L69), it is thrown if the component cannot find `window.google`, but then it sets a timeout and tries again. If you type `window.google` in the JS console, and it shows `{maps: {…}}` it means that the script _was_ loaded eventually.

Comment: I was able to get your code working with the autocomplete component locally. Here's what I did:

1. Used the `apiKey=MY_KEY` prop with a Google Maps key I happened to have.
2. Went to https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/overview (you may have to select your project)

Where it says "Enabled APIs" previously I only had Maps JavaScript API. I had to enable "Places API". So now it looks like this:

https://www.evernote.com/l/ATMDaHCMCldMX6vlsS1ZF_wqp719t3xRpzkB/image.png

Can you confirm you have Places API enabled?

Comment: I can confirm that I have both apis enabled. Is it possible that there is something wrong with my google account? It seems really erratic in when it throws the error. I have since tried a different key which allowed me to type in M and get suggestions, then it failed as I continued to type. Then I tried replacing the apiKey prop string value with single quotes instead of double, and now it throws the: "index.js:1 You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API..." error even after I undid that change. Would it be worth contacting Google about this? Again thank you for your time! @antun

Comment: Or is it possible that I did not npm install it correctly? Am I supposed to have typed in "npm i react-google-places-autocomplete" AND "npm install --save react-google-places-autocomplete". I only did the second. Also I believe I was in the project folder when I typed the command. Is this the right thing to do? @antun

Comment: Regarding the key, you can double-check you're using the correct one by going to the credentials section in the Google console, and re-copying your key there. Also click the key itself to make sure it's currently unrestricted, to eliminate any key authentication issues.

Comment: Regarding the npm install, the second command (`npm install --save react-google-places-autocomplete`) installs the package locally (i.e. in `./node_modules`) *and* updates your package.json file to indicate that the react-google-places-autocomplete should be installed every time you (or someone else) runs `npm install` with no arguments. So you installed it correctly. (You can also check it's in node_modules, but if it wasn't you'd get an exception when you tried to import the package in your JS code and use it.)

Comment: The key is correct. Looking in the package.json file and node_modules there's reference to both: "react-google-places-autocomplete", and "react-places-autocomplete". Is it possible that these are interfering with one another? I recall installing the first but not the second.

Comment: They shouldn't be interfering because you are importing the one that you want to use with `import GooglePlacesAutocomplete from 'react-google-places-autocomplete';` That's the one that your code is using. If you want to test I supposed you could delete node_modules, and reinstall (by running just `npm install` which should install only what's specified in package.json).

Comment: Fair enough. Do you have any clue what may be causing this problem? Everything api is enabled and I am using the correct apikey in the props.

Comment: Like I said, your example works just fine for me locally when I build and run it in a simple React app using my own  Google maps key. The only changes I made to your SearchBar were to *not* import ./SearchBar.css', since I don't have that file. So that leads me to think that there is something wrong with your Google Maps API key setup. One thing you could try is to run the pure (non-React) Google Places Autocomplete component with your key. Here's a JSFiddle I found that does that: https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/ykajnmkk/ If it works there then your key is OK.

Comment: Hey! It does appear to be a problem with my key! Mine doesn't work with the jsfiddle. It's strange though, because I know I have both enabled as seen here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s617/sh/3b7f77e9-4b7b-e89e-cb75-75a27d1b7038/cd016920e26ef9b7174e032424726c6f. Also in the places API row it is showing that there are requests but that they end in error. I have since requested a new key but the same thing happened. Additionally, the keys I've received are different from the one in the jsfiddle because mine include underscores and dashes whereas that one does not. @antun

Comment: Also would it be alright to use the key in that example in my project or would it be frowned upon? This is just a learning experience project, the Google Autocomplete Component is the last part I want to add to it before moving on. I would really like to see this project through! @antun

Comment: I can't say whether it's OK to use that key or not. It's not mine; I just found that fiddle via a search. You definitely set your key to be unrestricted, correct? I can see in your screenshot that they're enabled, but there's a different setting to make them unrestricted - i.e. not need a authentication.